# Django query for linking related data in template

Tags: django, templates, join, models

I have two tables of data in a Django app, one containing shipping vessel details and the other containing offers related to individual vessels. My models are as follows:

```
class Vessel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    vesseltype = models.ForeignKey(VesselType)
    capacity = models.IntegerField()
    length = models.FloatField()
    beam = models.FloatField()
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    activities = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    category = models.IntegerField()
    display_order = models.IntegerField()
    published = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Offer(models.Model):
    vessel = models.ForeignKey(Vessel)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    date = models.DateField()
    duration = models.IntegerField()
    itinerary = models.TextField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    display_order = models.IntegerField()
    link = models.URLField()
    published = models.BooleanField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

In my views.py I have the following code:

```
def home(request):
    vessels = Vessel.objects.filter(published='y').order_by('display_order')
    offers = Offer.objects.filter(vessel__published__exact='y').filter(published='y').order_by('display_order')
    t = loader.get_template('index.html')
    c = Context({
        'vessels' : vessels,
        'offers' : offers,
    })
```

In the template I need to display multiple divs each containing the vessel name, some of the vessel details and any number of offers related to that vessel.

I've looked at queries trying to link the offers in with each vessel and I've also tried identifying the vessel name inside loop code in the template to just display an offer if the vessel.id and offer.vessel match up.

So far, nothing has been successful with just getting errors on the query side and separate lists of vessel names and offers by going the template way. How do I join this information so I could just use something like this in the template:

```
for offer in offers:
    offer.vessel.name
    offer.vessel.category
    offer.description
    offer.price
```

or am I expecting too much? Been at this for several hours and can't find a solution in the docs but it's probably obvious. Changing the query, the view code or the template is not a problem.

Comment: You can already do exactly as your example code shows (once you wrap the references in template tag syntax). Garry Cairns' answer will make things a bit more efficient, though.

Comment: Apologies for lack of template tags, it was just to show pseudo-codeish what I was trying to achieve. With my code as it was above I could get to offer.description and offer.price but I kept getting an error about no attribute name when I tried to use offer.vessel.name. However, name was accessible through vessel.name so not sure what happened there. Checked my code to make sure it was the same as I entered above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to change your `view` code. You want a queryset like `Offer.objects.all().select_related()`. [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) will make sure you don't hit the database every time your loop executes because it will follow foreign keys to the end before executing a query.

You're also using the wrong [template syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#for). It needs to be something like:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
{{ object.attribute }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Garry, works great. I had followed links round the Django docs trying to find something like this but none of them ended on select_related.

Comment: Just to reiterate, you don't need `select_related()` for the foreign-key object reference syntax to work, it just makes it more efficient by avoiding an extra db call per row.